# Как использовать объект вместо функции?

Tags: javascript

[Тут](https://jsfiddle.net/spjoms2w/) через функцию создал объект со скрытой от внешнего доступа переменной и методом для работы с этой переменной:

```
function Machine() {
  var petrol = 100;

  this.getPetrol = function() {
    return petrol;
  };

  this.setPetrol = function(value) {
    petrol = value;
  };
}

var machine = new Machine();
var p = machine.getPetrol();
machine.setPetrol(5);
var newP = machine.getPetrol();
console.log(p, newP);
```

Теперь хотел бы записать тот же самый объект, но не через функцию, а через непосредственно объект. Помогите пожалуйста это сделать, [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/L738Lcmy/) моя попытка:

```
var Machine = {
  this.petrol = 100,

  this.getPetrol = function() {
    return petrol;
  },

  this.setPetrol = function(value) {
    petrol = value;
  }
}

var machine = new Machine();
machine.getPetrol();
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L738Lcmy/1/

Comment: а поле `petrol` так же должно быть защищено от внешнего доступа?

Comment: без функции аналогичный объект никак не получится.

Comment: @ThisMan желательно. но не обязательно

Comment: @Grundy потому что блок в отличие от функции не ограничивает область видимости?

Comment: @cyklop77, в данном случае у тебя **нет** блока, у тебя есть литерал объекта, и внутрь ты не можешь поместить произвольный код, как в функцию-конструктор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В литерале объекта поля описываются в следующем формате:

```
fieldName : fieldvalue
```

В первом примере ты добавляешь в свой объект два поля: `getPetrol`, `setPetrol`.

Формально аналогичный объект можно записать так:

```
var petrol = 100;
var Machine = {

  getPetrol : function() {
    return petrol;
  },

  setPetrol : function(value) {
    petrol = value;
  }
}
```

---

```js
var petrol = 100;
var Machine = {

  getPetrol: function() {
    return petrol;
  },

  setPetrol: function(value) {
    petrol = value;
  }
}

console.log(Machine.getPetrol());
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое что приходит на ум, помять свойство [defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

Либо дать доступ только по уникальной ссылке через [es6 symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)